# Can I start the VM in openVZ once the checkpoint is completed during vzdump?

Tags: linux, kernel, backup, openvz, dump

I have a VM with huge amount of data, close to 800GB. I was taking a vzdump of this VM. During the vzdump, openvz suspends the vm and does a check point and does a final sync of data before completing the vzdump operations. refer the log below.

The problem is, the final sycn takes lots of time. It has taken more than 4 hours, during this time, my VM is in suspended state. Can I restart the VM while the vzdump is still going on (mainly the final sync)

I don't want the vm to be suspend (unavailable) for longtime.

Please find the log below....

```
INFO: Starting new backup job - vzdump --compress --dumpdir /Server-Backup --tmpdir /Server-Backup/data --suspend 196
INFO: Starting Backup of VM 196 (openvz)
INFO: status = CTID 196 exist mounted running
INFO: starting first sync /vz/private/196 to /Server-Backup/data/vzdumptmp811041
INFO: Number of files: 5
INFO: Number of files transferred: 3
INFO: Total file size: 1002097869596 bytes
INFO: Total transferred file size: 1002097869596 bytes
INFO: Literal data: 1002097869596 bytes
INFO: Matched data: 0 bytes
INFO: File list size: 125
INFO: File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
INFO: File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
INFO: Total bytes sent: 1002220196263
INFO: Total bytes received: 77
INFO: sent 1002220196263 bytes  received 77 bytes  9822943.55 bytes/sec
INFO: total size is 1002097869596  speedup is 1.00
INFO: first sync finished (102028 seconds)
INFO: suspend vps
INFO: Setting up checkpoint...
INFO:   suspend...
INFO:   get context...
INFO: Checkpointing completed successfully
INFO: final sync /vz/private/196 to /Server-Backup/data/vzdumptmp811041
```

The final sync command got stuck for more than 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is,

1. We killed the rsync process which was initiated by vzdump (there were two)
2. Once we kill rsync, the vzdump process was exited
3. after that, resume/stop/start the VM didn't work
4. vzctl chkpnt VEID --resume (this command helped to start the VM)